# Commit question in PLSQL and Zend Framework

Tags: plsql, zend-framework, plsql-package, laminas

I would like your point of view about writing Oracle PL/SQL stored procedures and calling them in a Zend framework 3 controller.

If in my PL/SQL strored procedure I have a commit at the end of my procedure, and I use it in a controller with in proper transaction code, if there is an exception in my PHP code after calling the stored procedure, does the commit set in the database ? even if in my PHP code the rollback function is called ?

Answer (score 0):

Once your PL/SQL procedure issues `COMMIT`, that's it. Any subsequent rollback won't have any influence on what you already committed.

Comment: Thanks you very much @littlefoot